# Java alexa lambda function has some limit in time/operations?

Tags: java, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I'm writing a simple skill similart to the java airplane facts sample and I have two strange behaviours:

1) the same code in one intent works correctly, but in another causes an error;

2) I can't remove an element from a public static List!
I will try to explain better with a very close example.
I have two Intents that we can call:
- ActionIntent;
- StopIntent.

The first intent retrieves a list (of type List) retrieved from a class Constants and returns an attribute of a random CustomObject --
this works correctly.
Then it should set the object to Session Attributes and remove it from the list, because the next time the response should be a second attribute of the last CustomObject plus the first attribute of the new CustomObject. Does it make sense?

Here is the code:

```
// this row works correctly on the other intent
Map<String, Object> sessionAttributes = input.getAttributesManager().getSessionAttributes();

CustomObject last=(sessionAttributes.get("last")!=null) ? (CustomObject)sessionAttributes.get("last") : null;

List<CustomObject> allObjects = MAPPER.convertValue(Constants.getAllObjects(), List.class);

int index = new Random().nextInt(tutti.size());

CustomObject new = allObjects.get(index);

// a simple method that contains allObjects.remove(index) because it didn't work here but also this cause an error
Constants.removeCustomObjectFromList(index);

sessionAttributes.put("ultimoNome", nuovoNome);

String title = Constants.SKILL_TITLE;
String primaryText =new.getTrue();
String secondaryText =(last!=null) ?last.getFalse() : "";

String speechText = "" + secondaryText + " "+primaryText + "?";

return input.getResponseBuilder()
.withSpeech(speechText)
.withSimpleCard(title, primaryText)
.withReprompt(speechText)
.build();
```

If I comment out the rows linked to the sessionAttribute and the Constants.removeCustomObjectFromList it works correctly but, as I said, the reference to sessionAttribute works correctly in another intent and I must remove CustomObjects from my initial list because the user should listen two time the same thing!
Could someone tell me where to find good info on this subject?

Answer (score 0):

https://ask-sdk-for-nodejs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Managing-Attributes.html

Above is the official docs. It can be a bit difficult to understand a couple things in there due to lack of extensive explanation, but for the most part everything you need is there. As for your issue, I don't know if this is the only cause, but I don't think getAttributesManager() is a function, unless that's something you've defined. Your code:

```
Map<String, Object> sessionAttributes = input.getAttributesManager().getSessionAttributes();
```

Can you try:

`Map<String, Object> sessionAttributes = input.attributesManager.getSessionAttributes();`

instead?